For an open immersion $ j : U \to \operatorname{Spec} B$, $\operatorname{Spec} j^*j_*\mathcal{B} \cong \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{B}$?
First, let me arrange some necessary preliminary. In section $(11.2)$ of the Gortz, Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry, they argue :
If $A$ is a ring, $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$, and $B$ and $A$-algebra, we have seen in Proposition 3.4 that for every $X$-scheme $T$ there exists a bijection
$$ \operatorname{Hom}_X(T,\mathrm{Spec}B) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{(A-Alg)}(B, \Gamma(T, \mathcal{O}_T)) \tag{11.2.1}$$
which is functorial in $T$ and in $B$. In other words, the $A$-scheme $\operatorname{Spec}B$ represents the functor $T \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_{(A-Alg)}(B,\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)).$ We will now globalize this construction.
Proposition 11.1. Let $X$ be a scheme and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra. Then there exists an $X$-scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{B})$ such that for all $X$-schemes $f:T\to X$ there are bijections, functoiral in $T$,
$$ \operatorname{Hom}_X(T, \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{B})) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{(\mathcal{O}_X-Alg)}(\mathcal{B},f_*\mathcal{O}_T). \tag{11.2.2}$$
In other words, $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{B})$ represents the functor
$$ (Sch/X)^{\operatorname{opp}} \to (Sets), \ (f:T\to X) \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_{(\mathcal{O}_X-Alg)}(\mathcal{B},f_*\mathcal{O}_T).$$
$\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{B}$ is called the spectrum of $\mathcal{B}$. If needed, I will upload it's proof.
Second, question : Let $ j : U \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}B$ be an open immersion. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_U$-algebra. Then (relative) spectrums $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{B}$ and $\operatorname{Spec} j^{*}j_{*}\mathcal{B}$ are isomorphic?
My first trial : perhaps, next is true? : For all $U$-scheme $f:T\to U$,
$$\operatorname{Hom}_U(T, \operatorname{Spec}(j^* j_* \mathcal{B})) \xrightarrow{\cong }\operatorname{Hom}_{(\mathcal{O}_U-Alg)}(j^* j_* \mathcal{B}, f_* \mathcal{O}_T)  \xrightarrow{\cong ? }\operatorname{Hom}_{(\mathcal{O}_U-Alg)}(\mathcal{B},f_*\mathcal{O}_T) \xrightarrow{\cong} \operatorname{Hom}_U(T,\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{B})) $$ ? ; i.e., the middle map is also isomorphism? If so, then $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{B}$ and $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal j^{*}f_{*}(\mathcal{B})$ represent same functor, so that they are isomorphic.
In fact, this question originates from following proof of Lemma ( Lei fu, Etale cohomology theory, Lemma 7.7.9 ) :

Lemma 7.7.9. Let $B$ be a normal strictly henselian noetherian local ring, $V$ an open subset of $\operatorname{Spec}B$ containing all prime ideals of height $1$, $U$ the inverse image of $V$ under the canonical morphims $\pi : \operatorname{Spec}B\{T\} \to \operatorname{Spec}B$ ( C.f. For $B\{T\}$, refer to his book Lemma 7.7.8. ), $U_m$ the inverse images of $U$ under the canonical closed immersions $\operatorname{Spec}B[T]/T^{m+1}B[T] \to \operatorname{Spec}B\{T\}$, and $f : U' \to U$ an etale covering space ( ; i.e., finite etale morphism ). If the morphisms $f_m : U_m'\to U_m$ induced by base change are trivial etale covering spaces for all $m$, then $f: U' \to U$ is a tirivial etale covering space.

Proof. Let $j : U \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} B\{T\}$ be the open immersion. $j_* f_* \mathcal{O}_{U'}$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}B\{T\}}$-module ($\because$ Hartshorne, II.5.8 ) Let
$$ C:= \Gamma(\operatorname{Spec}B\{T\} , j_{*}f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{U'})=\Gamma(U',\mathcal{O}_{U'}).$$
We then have
$$ j_* f_*\mathcal{O}_{U'} \cong \tilde{C}$$
Since $f$ is affine, we have
$$ U' \cong \operatorname{Spec} f_*\mathcal{O}_{U'} \stackrel{?}{\cong}\operatorname{Spec} j^* j_* f_* \mathcal{O}_{U'} .$$
( Next proof is omitted .. )
Why the final isomorphism is true?
Can anyone help?

If $V \subset U$ is open, then $$j^*j_*\mathcal{B}(V) = 
(j_*\mathcal{B})|_{U}(V) = j_*\mathcal{B}(V) = \mathcal{B}(V),$$ so this isomorphism just comes from the sheaf level.

O.K. It was an easy question. Thank you :)
